# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1) when load same json file

Tags: python, json, flask

I created a Twitter sentiment analysis system where users can input the keywords and then get the sentiment results as a tweet. The tweet data and sentiment results that have been obtained will be stored in a JSON file (datacoba4.JSON) and will continue to be updated (append).
After saving, I want to use the data in the datacoba4.json file (including those that have been updated) to print again. But I always get error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1).

This is the code:

```
with open('datacoba4.json', 'r+') as ab:
    dict1 = {"Keyword": que}
    dict2 = {"Tweet": hasiltweets}
    dict3 = {"Sentimen": hasilprediksi}             
                   
    json.dumps([dict1, dict2, dict3],  indent=4).replace('{', ',', 1)
    ab.seek(0,2)
    ab.write(json.dumps([dict1, dict2, dict3]).replace('{', ',', 1))
    
with open('datacoba4.json', 'r') as ae:
    pew =  json.load(ae)
    print(pew[1]['Tweet'])
```

And this is my JSON file format:

[,"Keyword": "jokowi"}, {"Tweet": ["example", "example2", "example3"]}, {"Sentimen": ["Positif", "Negatif", "Negatif"]}]

Comment: You intentionally mess up the JSON by replacing the first curly brace with a comma. Don’t do that.  You can’t append to JSON. Consider [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format

Comment: oh my bad, yeahh, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample from the JSON file you included is not valid JSON: the second character is a comma and the opening brace `{` is missing. This is essentially what the error message says.

Comment: oh rightt, i just replace the { with comma. Thank you. 
But, i get another error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5168 (char 5167). 
And this is the JSON format [{"Keyword": "jokowi"}, {"Tweet": ["Example1", "Example2"]}, {"Sentimen": ["Positif", "Negatif"]}] [{"Keyword": "jokowi2"}, {"Tweet": ["Example3", "Example3"]}, {"Sentimen": ["Positif", "Negatif"]}] [{"Keyword": "jokowi3"}, {"Tweet": ["Example5", "Example6"]}, {"Sentimen": ["Positif", "Negatif"]}] 
am i wrong again?

Comment: @Casseyk Yes, this is the same type of error, which means that there are more issues with JSON format.